# Boosting the coordination factor in a Solr query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a problem with the default Solr scoring algorithm that's specific the domain of my collection. In my domain, documents that contain all the query terms or most query terms are substantially more relevant than documents that contain only a few terms. I would like to boost the score of documents so that the more terms that match, the higher the score. I'm aware to the fact that solr already boosts such documents by multiplying the score by the coordination factor. However, the coordination factor is not significant enough for me, and I wish to raise it to a certain power. I'm also familiar with the ExtendedDismax parser's Minimum-Should-Match feature, but that feature doesn't solve my problem because I don't want to eliminate the documents that don't match enough terms, I just want to "punish" them.

Is there a way to increase the significance of the coordination factor? I'll also accept other solutions that don't make any use of the coordination factor if they solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to just write your own similarity.  You can override the [coord method](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html#coord%28int,%20int%29) with whatever you like, and the implementation of it is pretty simple really  Something like:

```java
public class MySimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {
    @Override
    public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        return super.coord(overlap, maxOverlap)^2;
    }
}
```

You can bring in your own similarity implementation [in the schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity):

```xml
<similarity class="this.is.MySimilarity"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer because it solves the problem as I've stated it. The problem with the solution is that the power to which the coordination factor is raised can't be given as a parameter to the query. I haven't been clear about that when describing the problem, but I'll have to boost the coordination factor differently every time. Is it possible to implement it in a way that allows me to do that? I was thinking about a boosting function query, but I don't see how to access the coord parameter that way.

Comment: Not aware of anything like that, I'm afraid. The only solutions that come to mind are: **A**-Duplicate the field, and use a `SchemaSimilarityFactory` to apply the custom similarity to one, and a default to the other, and query the correct field, **B**-Access `IndexSearcher` directly, where you could access the Similarity before running your query (something like `indexSearcher.getSimilarity().setCoordBoostFactor(2); indexSearcher.search(query);`), **C**-Post-processing, which is probably only feasible if you can count on documents being relatively short, and queries being relatively simple.